# Explanation is required for the logs of the NFSD service - laundromat_main - sleeping for XX seconds

Tags: zabbix, nfs4

Could you provide an explanation of the messages from the log file /var/log/messages?
What does it mean?

NFSD: laundromat service - starting

NFSD: laundromat_main - sleeping for XX seconds

Note: There is a problem with the port being unavailable from Zabbix trigger - net.tcp.service/net.tcp.port from time to time.